# Need clarification regarding SGD Optimizer

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I have a question regarding `SGD Optimizer`.

There are 3 types of `Gradient Descent Algorithm`:

1. Batch Gradient Descent
2. Mini-Batch Gradient Descent and
3. Stochastic Gradient Descent

**`Stochastic Gradient Descent`** is an `Algorithm` in which one `Instance` from `Training Set` is taken at `Random` and the **`Weights`** are updated with respect to that `Instance`.

**`SGD Optimizer`** is slightly deviating from the above definition where it can accept the **`batch_size`** of more than 1. Can someone clarify this deviation?

Below code seems to be in line with the definition of **`Stochastic Gradient Descent`**:

```
model.compile(optimizer = 'sgd', loss = 'mse')
model.fit(x, y,epochs = 500, batch_size = 1,verbose=1)
```

However, below code seems to be confusing/deviating (since `batch_size` > 1):

```
model.compile(optimizer = 'sgd', loss = 'mse')
model.fit(x, y,epochs = 500, batch_size = 32, verbose=1)
```

Thank you in advance for the clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from Wikipedia:

> It can be regarded as a stochastic approximation of gradient descent optimization, since it replaces the actual gradient (calculated from the entire data set) by an estimate thereof (calculated from a randomly selected subset of the data)

So the three types you mentioned are all SGD. Even if you use all your data to perform an SGD iteration, it's still a stochastic estimate of the *actual* gradient; as upon collecting new data (your dataset doesn't include all the data in universe) your estimate will change, hence stochastic.